# Loglikelihood similarity for document clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, similarity, text-mining

I’m using following loglikelihood formula to compare the similarity between a document and a cluster:
log p(d|c) = sum (c(w,d) * log p(w|c)); 
c(w,d) is the frequency of a word in a document and p(w|c) is the likelihood of word w being generated by a cluster c.

The problem is that based on this similarity the document is often assigned to the wrong cluster. If I assign the document to the cluster with the highest log p(d|c) (as it is usually negative value I take –log p(d|c)) then it will be the cluster that contains a lot of words from a document but the probability of these words in the cluster is low. 
If I assign the document to the cluster with the lowest log p(d|c) then it will be the cluster that has intersection with a document only in one word. 
Can someone explain me how to use the loglikelihood correctly? I try to implement this function in java. I already looked on google scholar, but didn’t found suitable explanation of loglikelihood in text mining. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log likelihood formulation is correct for describing a document with a multinomial model (words in each document are generated independently from a multinomial distribution).

To get the maximum likelihood cluster assignment, you should be taking the cluster assignment, c, that maximizes log p(d|c). log p(d|c) should be a negative number - the maximum is the number closest to zero.

If you are getting cluster assignments that don't make sense, it is likely that this is because the multinomial model does not describe your data well. So, the answer to your question is most likely that you should either choose a different statistical model or use a different clustering method.